# Special case in the Unicode String.StartsWith function

Tags: string, unicode

I have implemented a utf8 string class in C++ with full case-folding case insensitive comparison. By full case-folding I mean a case insensitive comparison where `Maße` and `MASSE` would be equal. I use the same comparison function in the `StartsWith(...)` member function which returns true if it starts with the string specified in the argument. There is a special case where I'm not sure what is the correct behavior:

```
String myString = "Maß"; 
bool result = myString.StartsWith("MAS", CaseSensitivity::CaseInsensitive);
```

So, using full case folding I can convert `Maß` to `mass` and `MAS` to `mas`. So basically the StartsWith function should return true, because `mass` starts with `mas`. But the problem might be that not the whole `ß` was processed, only the half of it. Is this correct? Or should I return true only when the whole codepoint was processed?

Comment: what is `String` and have you done any string normalization before comparing?

Comment: It is not clear who processes the string. Change passive to active in the last few sentences so the description becomes more meaningful.